# Jmeter non GUI mode csv report not showing latency

Tags: ssh, jmeter, sftp, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to get the jmeter html report for file transfer in SFTP protocol.
I am using `SSH SFTP Protocol` plugin and added `Simple Data Writer` to that thread group.

I have created my own sftp server using Apache MINA. Jmeter script will hit the server which i created and uploads the file.

Script Parameters:

- Thread Group -  250
- Ramp up period - 50
- Loop Count - 1

After running the script in non GUI mode as `nohup sh jmeter.sh -n -t Singlepart_MultipleThread_RampUp.jmx -l Singlepart_MultipleThread_RampUp.jtl`. I do get a csv generated which i convert into html report command `jmeter -g <csv> -o <destination_folder>`.

The html report created shows `Latency vs Time` and `Latency vs Request` as zero and even the csv report shows latency column as zero.

Below is my user.properties file

**user.properties**

```
# Latencies Over Time graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyOverTimeGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.title=Latencies Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}

# Latencies Vs Request graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyVSRequestGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.title=Latencies Vs Request
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.exclude_controllers=true
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}
```

**jmeter.properties**

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results file configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This section helps determine how result data will be saved.
# The commented out values are the defaults.

# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv

# The below properties are true when field should be saved; false otherwise
#
# assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
#
# legitimate values: none, first, all
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
#
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
# Only available with HttpClient4
jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=true

# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

# For use with Comma-separated value (CSV) files or other formats
# where the fields' values are separated by specified delimiters.
# Default:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
# For TAB, one can use:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t

# Only applies to CSV format files:
# Print field names as first line in CSV
#jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true

# Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data files.
# Use commas to separate the names. For example:
#sample_variables=SESSION_ID,REFERENCE
# N.B. The current implementation saves the values in XML as attributes,
# so the names must be valid XML names.
# By default JMeter sends the variable to all servers
# to ensure that the correct data is available at the client.

# Optional xml processing instruction for line 2 of the file:
# Example:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../extras/jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl"?>
# Default value:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=

# Prefix used to identify filenames that are relative to the current base
#jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/

# AutoFlush on each line written in XML or CSV output
# Setting this to true will result in less test results data loss in case of Crash
# but with impact on performances, particularly for intensive tests (low or no pauses)
# Since JMeter 2.10, this is false by default
#jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

So basically facing issue at two places:

1. How to get the latency value?
2. When i provide `Ramp up` value as 1, the script with `Thread Group =50` takes around 16 seconds to complete the upload, whereas if i give `Ramp up` something other than 1 such as 10 then the script ends after 10 secs exact, irrespective of file is getting uploaded or not and providing vague results in html report as well.

Any idea how to solve this. Or need to do anything else in script.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot as the plugin you're using [doesn't call](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler/search?q=latency&unscoped_q=latency) [SampleResult.setLatency()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setLatency-long-) function anywhere

   [image]

   theoretically it should be possible to [request the functionality from the plugin developers](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler/issues)
2. Setting 10 seconds ramp-up period for 50 virtual users means that JMeter starts with 1 virtual user and gradually increases the load to 50 within 10 seconds duration. Make sure to have enough loops defined in the Thread Group as you may run into the situation when 1st user has already finished uploading the file and was terminated and 2nd hasn't need started so you have maximum 1 user concurrency (it can be checked using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener). See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected/) for more detailed explanation if needed.